# Moving Laravel project to new PC

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I have moved my project from my pc to my laptop and a lot of lines do not work such as Auth, Form, @Extends, @Section.

For example, this is a piece of navbar.blade.php my navbar is changing upon the type of account, after moving the project the if command doesn't check for the authentication, all users are dealt with as a **guests**

```
@if(Auth::check())

              @if(Auth::user()->Account_type == 'Student')
            <li><a href="/myprojects">My projects</a></li>
              @ENDIF

              @if(Auth::user()->Account_type == 'Admin')
              <li><a href="/AdminDashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
               @ENDIF
@ENDIF
```

I have tried

```
Composer Install
Composer Update
composer dumpautoload
```

Nothing worked for me

Comment: have you got an any error? This information is not enough to understand. Please add more detail.

Comment: Define: `a lot of lines do not work`

Comment: The website has missing features and missing pages

Comment: @Jerodev they are inactive, they do nothing

Comment: try to remove vendor directory and run composer install

Comment: @atouiahmed didn't work

Comment: how did you move it? copy and paste?

Comment: compressed all files and copied it @KapitanTeemo

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya added more details please look at it

Comment: @Jerodev added more details please look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy your project, database from PC to Laptop. Change .env
You can see project is working fine. I have also do some thing.

I am not facing any problem.